# How to use If condition in ui_component file sales_order_grid.xml

Tags: magento2, layout, uicomponent

In Magento version (less than 2.0.5) sales_order_grid.xml is like

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <container name="listing_top">...</container>
```

but in Higher version (above 2.0.6) its like

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">...</listingToolbar>
```

Now I am facing cross version issue in my custom module. I cannot even use ifconfig here bcoz of a ui_component XML file.

Any suggestions? It's urgent!

Comment: Where u want to use if condition?

Comment: I want to create functionality like if magento version is Leass than 2.0.6 then it will call
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <container name="listing_top">...</container> @Ankit Shah

Comment: What happens when u upgrade to latest 2.1.5?

Comment: I was thinking if there is any functionality through which I can manage both using if condition or something

Comment: It's clear in higher version its  "listingToolbar" tag is defined and in lower version "container" tag is defined which is creating problem because when i run it on 2.1 its work with <listingToolbar> tag & in lower with <container> tag

Comment: May be this can help : https://www.cminds.com/magento-layout-update-incompatibility-versions-2-0-x-2-1-x/